# Checking length of Arrays before setting values

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I have to set values in a list of string arrays. How do I write the code to avoid an array out of bound exception.
e.g. this is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < childs.getLength(); i++)
{
    String[] slotValues = _newValues.get(i);
    if (allSlots) {
        NodeList slots = childs.item(i).getChildNodes();
        for (int j = 0; j < slotValues.length; j++) {
            XmlUtil.setTextContent(slots.item(j), slotValues[j]); 
        }
    } else {
        for (int j = 0; j < slotValues.length; j++) {
            XmlUtil.setTextContent(XmlUtil.getFeature(_slotNames[j], childs.item(i)), slotValues[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

I am a beginner and I do not know how to check if the length of values that I am trying to set in the structure does not give array out of bound exception. i.e. it should be equal to the length of array.

Comment: You might get help quicker if you use a language tag.

Comment: Looks like Java.

Comment: You are already doing it in the for loop!   i < childs.getLength(),  j < slotValues.length;

Answer (score 0):

> I am a beginner and I do not know how to check if the length of values
>   that I am trying to set in the structure does not give array out of
>   bound exception. i.e. it should be equal to the length of array.

Since collections in Java are 0 based, having array `arr` the first element is `arr[0]` and the last element will be `arr[arr.length-1]`. Knowing this you can ensure that your iteration variable (array index) is always `>=0` and `<array.length`.

Having `index >= arr.length` will result in `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Bare in mind, that in your code, you are using single iteration variable to index multiple arrays like here

`XmlUtil.getFeature(_slotNames[j], childs.item(i)), slotValues[j])`

You are using _slotNames and slotValues with the same index, but you are limiting index with `j < slotValues.length` so it is dependent on slotValues length. If both arrays are of equal length, that is fine. But if they are not, then you will get mentioned exception if `_slotNames` will have less elements then `slotValues`.